# Google App Engine - What's counted as Front End?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a small NodeJS running on an Google AE instance, I'm able to get the free 9h of back-end usage (which is nice). I saw a post that said python would be counted as front end is this true?

So if I ported the Node scrip to Python I would get the 28h free usage?

I can't seem to find any docs on GCP about this.

---

The app is just a simple HTTP listener with on events (need to run 24/7)
I like Google AE for all its login tools etc, so free Compute engine is off the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not an instance is "frontend" or "backend" is based on your [scaling setting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Instances). So if you use manual scaling, you can't have "frontend" instance and if you use automatic scaling, then you can't have "backend" instance.

Comment: Thanks, never saw that part on the docs. There was a post that was saying that it was what run time was. Happy It clear it up

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs run 24/7 then you need to using Appengine Flexible. At least your instance still run in Google Compute Engine.

Comment: No I use a standard instance, with a web interface and uses Stack drive up time checker running every 10min to keep it up